# Cumulative prices based on dates that cover different pricing periods

Tags: excel-formula, date-range

I am trying to calculate how much someone needs to pay me, where the ticket prices are set for a certain period.

Guest Name | Arrival Date | Departure Date | adults | Child | Total |

J.Bloggs   | 14/11/2019   | 18/11/2019     | 5      | 2     | 7 |

Price 01/11/2019 ~ 04/11/2019 = £3.40

Price 05/11/2019 ~ 15/11/2019 = £2.50

Price 16/11/2019 ~ 30/11/2019 = £1.90

I need to workout how to charge J.Bloggs £2.50 for 2 nights (14th & 15th) then £1.90 for 3 nights (16th, 17th and 18th) = £10.70 * 7 people = £74.90

The blue columns is the raw data, the green columns are formula based (I don't need the Price column, I was just using to work out the fees).

[image: Raw Data]  [image: Pricing Table]

This is the formula I have in the price column at the moment, but know that won't work when the tickets are covering multiple periods.

```
{=INDEX(Pricing!$C:$C,MATCH(1,(Pricing!$A:$A<=IF(ISTEXT($A2),DATEVALUE($A2),$A2))*(Pricing!$B:$B>=IF(ISTEXT($A2),DATEVALUE($A2),$A2)),0))}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SUMPRODUCT with INDEX/MATCH:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(INDEX($C$8:$C$10,MATCH(ROW(INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,A2):INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,B2)),$A$8:$A$10)))*E2
```

this is an array formula and requires the use of Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

`ROW(INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,A2):INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,B2))` creates an array of the dates.

`MATCH(...,$A$8:$A$10)` Takes that array and finds where it falls in the lookup table.  Note: the lookup table must be sorted ascending.

`INDEX($C$8:$C$10,...)`  Takes each of those matches in turn and creates an array of the output prices.

`SUMPRODUCT(...)` adds all the values together.

Then we simple multiply it by the number of guests.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help on this. I tried using the formula you have suggested but i'm getting the answer £17.50 which is a sum of the prices I want, but then it doesn't multiply the amount of guests, even though I have the *E2 element to do this.
=SUMPRODUCT(INDEX($C$8:$C$10,MATCH(ROW(INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,A2):INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,B2)),$A$8:$A$10)))*E2

Comment: Try confirming with Ctrl-Shift-enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  It may need to be array entered.  My version of Excel no longer requires it, so sometimes I don't know if the formula does.

Comment: Thank you, My version is Microsoft 2013, but the formula works in Office365 perfectly.

Comment: The ctrl + Shift doesn't work on my excel version, do you know anyway around this?

Comment: This should work in 2013.  there is nothing in the formula that is unique to office 365.   Make sure the dates are true dates and not text that look like dates. also make sure the numbers are all number and not numbers stored as text.

Comment: Thanks Scott, It seems to be part working. it knows 14/11/2019 is between the 05/11/2019 ~ 15/11/2019 price range, so uses the correct price, but then it takes that price and multiply it by the amount of guests, it doesn't take into account the price changes.
However if I put the same formula in Office365 it is working as expected.

Comment: Without seeing the actual workbook from the 2013, and no I will not open a file from someone I do not know, I cannot help.  It works for me in 2013.